# Change watchOS deployment target after upgrading to Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos

I have an iOS app with watchOS 1.0 extension. After upgrading xCode to 7.2, only watchOS 2.0, 2.1 are available to select as the deployment target. I do not want to migrate to watchOS 2.0, at least for now, due to the massive amount of work involved. How do I keep it at watchOS 1.0?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add different target for Watch OS 1.0 and Watch OS 2.0 as per your needs.

Please refer image to add target.

[image]

Comment: I added a target for watchOS 1, but under the build settings for the new target, I can only see watchOS Deployment Target Watchos 2.0 and 2.1, as before.